# focus & key board listner problem in cell table in gwt

Tags: gwt

I have one small problem i.e. one textbox is their when click on the text box the popup is shows below the text box.The popup contains  celltable

i write keypresslisner for textbox when i press Down And UP arrow the focus is set to be cellTable And also we still press down and up arrows its highlites the rows in celltable

```
     anyone  please tell me how to solve it...it's my request
```

When I wrote code like this:

box.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {

@Override
   public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {

```
if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == 38) {
 celltable.setFocus(true);
} else if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == 40) {
 celltable.setFocus(true);
}
```

}

});

only the focus is goes to the cell table

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little bit unclear, but I think you may be helped by `FocusPanel`:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html

Wrap your `CellTable` in this `FocusPanel` and you can do `setFocus()` on that instead. The `FocusPanel` has `addKeyPressHandler()`, so you can capture further keypress events there, also when your textbox has lost the focus.